# Dynamic image update using content property in CSS

Tags: css

Dynamic URL generation using `content` property in CSS:

```
ul li a:before{
  content: url( 'image'+ '1' +'.jpg' );
}
```

If I try to add dynamic value `1/2/3` in URL tag, value is not getting populated on screen. I debugged it and found that `+` sign is creating the issue if inserted inside the image URL.

Kindly suggest some approach to implement dynamic URL content using CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings in CSS with `+`. Where are you getting the values that you want to _"inject"_ into your CSS?

Comment: In li tag I have counter-increment : sites, which sets the incremental value and in content, I am trying to utilize that using counter(site)[instead of 1/2/3]. Kindly suggest any other approach if we can't do concatenation in CSS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value for `url()` has to be a single value and you're not able to concatenate strings for it like you can for the `content` property, i.e. you cannot do this with `url()`: `url( "image" counter( sites ) ".jpg" )`.

Comment: So what could be the alternative way for implementing this approach. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @rahulbilove JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. But we can't invoke function from css and I can't go for jquery in my code.